# How to perform COUNT aggregate function using hook_views_query_alter()?

Tags: views

I have fields post_date and nid in my view and I need to get count of nid upon group by post_date.
Using hook_views_query_alter(),

```
function custom_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {

  if ($view->name == 'tests') {     

    $query->add_field('node', 'nid', 'count', array('function' => 'count'));
    $query->add_field('node', 'post_date', 'post_date', array('function' => 'groupby'));
    $query->distinct=TRUE;

  }
}
```

However the sql query in the view is displaying **count(node.nid) as count** and **Group By date**
But the table result is performing only groupby function and not count function.
I can see the date column was grouped but the nid column is still showing the nid value but not the count value.

Post Date - Nid
05/20/2015  189519
05/19/2015  189520
05/18/2015  189521
05/17/2015  189556
05/15/2015  189515

I'm expecting something like this,

Post Date - Nid
05/20/2015  3
05/19/2015  2
05/18/2015  6
05/17/2015  1
05/15/2015  3

What am I missing in the hook?
Is there any other approach to achieve this?(excluding views calc, views aggregation plus, aggregation advanced settings; These modules doesn't help me to perform filters on the values after aggregation)
Refer [this link](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/173597/how-to-filter-the-whole-group-of-similar-rows-after-aggregation)   for more understanding of my problem.
Thanks.